# ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_7 to have shape (154, 154, 1) but got array with shape (200, 200, 3)

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to build CNN Autoencoder. Each training image(color) has size of 200*200. I got the error while compiling: `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_7 to have shape (154, 154, 1) but got array with shape (200, 200, 3)` with following code. How can the code can modified to work ?

```
autoencoder = Sequential()

autoencoder.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), input_shape=(200, 200, 3)))
autoencoder.add(Activation('relu'))
autoencoder.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

autoencoder.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
autoencoder.add(Activation('relu'))
autoencoder.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

autoencoder.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
autoencoder.add(Activation('relu'))
autoencoder.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))) # encoded

autoencoder.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
autoencoder.add(Activation('relu'))
autoencoder.add(UpSampling2D((2,2)))

autoencoder.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
autoencoder.add(Activation('relu'))
autoencoder.add(UpSampling2D((2,2)))

autoencoder.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3)))
autoencoder.add(Activation('relu'))
autoencoder.add(UpSampling2D((2,2)))

autoencoder.add(Conv2D(1, (3, 3)))
autoencoder.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')
```

Comment: when does this error occurs? the network compiles fine. could you provided the size of the input and the output? how do you train it? did you saw that your target is not the same shape of the input?

Comment: i want to train with set of color images with size: 200*200 and want to predict color image with same size. I am also unaware about how the shape of input flows top to bottom in above code.

Comment: add autoencoder.summary() at the end of the code (or after if in jupyter), you will see the size after every layer, you may want to check them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i see it, there are two main issues with your code above.

First is dimension decrease, from (200,200) to (154,154) witch can easily be solved by padding='same' to every Conv2D layer like this:

```
autoencoder = Sequential()

autoencoder.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), input_shape=(200, 200, 3), padding='same'))
autoencoder.add(Activation('relu'))
autoencoder.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

autoencoder.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same'))
autoencoder.add(Activation('relu'))
autoencoder.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

autoencoder.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same'))
autoencoder.add(Activation('relu'))
autoencoder.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))) # encoded

autoencoder.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same'))
autoencoder.add(Activation('relu'))
autoencoder.add(UpSampling2D((2,2)))

autoencoder.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), padding='same'))
autoencoder.add(Activation('relu'))
autoencoder.add(UpSampling2D((2,2)))

autoencoder.add(Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same'))
autoencoder.add(Activation('relu'))
autoencoder.add(UpSampling2D((2,2)))

autoencoder.add(Conv2D(1, (3, 3), padding='same'))
autoencoder.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')
```

Second issue is with your target. What you are trying to predict here with output `(200,200,1)` at your last `Conv2D` layer, with `sigmoid activation` and `binary_crossentropy loss` is a grayscale image. If this is what you want you have to train your model with y_train being 1 channel images (200,200,1) otherwise you can change your output to (200,200,3) like this:

change:

```
autoencoder.add(Conv2D(1, (3, 3), padding='same'))
```

to:

```
autoencoder.add(Conv2D(3, (3, 3), padding='same'))
```

Comment: Thanks, it solved my problem. What can be further changed in the output layer so that the output image is a color image with each channel value between [0-255] ?